# Change payment text and logo Opencart 2.2.0.0

Tags: php, paypal, opencart, undefined, standards

i need help in modify text of payment option in the fifth step of the checkout on my opencart ecommerce.
For example i want change the '' Paypal '' text to '' Paypal - credit card '' but if i only change a letter in the original file ( pp_standard.php ) when i arrive at step 5 in checkout i get a popup with '' error undefined ''.
The same thing happens with other payment method.
Here is the code of modified and not working pp_standard.php

```
<!--?php
// Text$_['text_title']             = 'PayPal - Carta di credito';
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

If it's possible i'd like to put a payment logo near the text.
The file is located at catalog/language/mylanguage/payment.
Thanks to all!

Comment: you should edit your payment module language file lines `$_['heading_title']      = 'PayPal Payments Standard';` to `$_['heading_title']      = 'PayPal credit Card';`

Comment: icons you can add using this extension: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=29551&filter_search=add%20payment%20logo&filter_license=0